# Why do I need to set the processing location for "asia-northeast1" in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

When querying datasets located in either the `US` or the `EU`, I don't need to specify the "processing location" in the UI for the query to work. In this case, it seems BigQuery is able to work out the appropriate "processing location" itself by looking at the referenced dataset.

However, when querying datasets located in `asia-northeast1`, then I always have to explicitly set the "processing location" to be the same (`asia-northeast1`) or the query will fail with:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the documentation, if you are referencing datasets outside of the `EU` or `US`, then you need to specify the same processing location.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-locations

> If your data is in a location other than the US or EU multi-region, you must specify the location when you perform actions such as loading data, **querying data**, and exporting data. When you query data using the BigQuery web UI, click Show Options, and for Processing Location, click Unspecified and choose your data's location. You can leave processing location set to unspecified if your data is in the US or EU multi-region location. When your data is in the US or the EU, the processing location is automatically detected.

Comment: BigQuery has updated, now we no need to specify the location

> When loading data, querying data, or exporting data, BigQuery determines the location to run the job based on the datasets referenced in the request. For example, if a query references a table in a dataset stored in the asia-northeast1 region, the query job will run in that region